# Converting UNIX time to datetime object in Jinja templates

Tags: python, google-app-engine, timestamp, python-datetime

I want to convert my timestamp to datetime in jinja2..

here's my sample code:

```
import time

date = time.time()
self.tv['date'] = date
```

sample html:

```
<p>{{ date }}</p>
```

I want to convert it to datetime using jinja2 in python..

thanks..

Answer (score 16):

Make a custom filter like

```
@app.template_filter('ctime')
def timectime(s):
    return time.ctime(s) # datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(s)
```

And use your template filter

```
{{ date | ctime }}
```

Comment: [`ctime()` uses server's timezone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149712/can-i-convert-timestamp-to-datetime-in-python-jinja2#comment45640509_15149724). Make sure it is what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You convert it before passing it to a template, eg:

```
>>> import time
>>> date = time.time()
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(date)
datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 1, 2, 57, 29, 472572)
```

And optionally use formatting:

```
>>> format(datetime.fromtimestamp(date), '%Y%m%d')
'20130301'
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply ...but I just want to do it in jinja2 because of some reasons.. is it possible in jinja2?..

Comment: @LeonardMark not unless you write a custom template filter - no

Comment: @JonClements: you can pass the module `time` to the template. Then you can do e.g. `{{ time.ctime(time.time()) }}`.

Comment: @LeonardMark: beware, `fromtimestamp(ts)` returns *local* (server) time -- a client might be in a different timezone from the server. Even if the timezone is correct, `fromtimestamp()` may fail for past/future dates if the local timezone had/may have different utc offsets (unrelated to DST) *and* if `fromtimestamp()` does not use the tz database on the given system. If you want a client time, pass the posix timestamp and render it on the client. Or use `pytz` and specify the timezone explicitly.

Answer (score -1):

Use this in the template:

```
{{ time | from_timestamp('%Y.%m.%d. %H:%M:%S UTC') }}
```

Comment: i couldn't find from_timestamp() in the list of builtin filters (https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#builtin-filters)

so you have to register this custom filter to environmentfilters first (https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/api/?highlight=filter#writing-filters)

Answer (score -2):

Use the following,
Data

```
{
    "timestamp": "1424197820"
}
```

Template

```
{{ timestamp|timestamp_to_time|datetimeformat('%a, %B %d') }}
```

Rendered

> Tue, February 17

[Source](https://support.sendwithus.com/jinja/jinja_time/#using-timestamp_to_time)

Comment: I get: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateAssertionError: no filter named 'datetimeformat'

Comment: true, the filter function must be added as a custom filter: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/api/?highlight=filter#writing-filters